# How to add master detail fields into custom view?

Tags: custom-view

I am learning how to use Salesforce custom view and successfully add object field into it but struggling to get master detail fields into it.

Comment: You cannot add detail record fields in the custom list view of the master record using standard point and click functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by just using the list view but if you really need it, you could create a field in the child object that would copy the value from the master via a workflow rule or a formula, that way you would have the same value in the child object.